# The average distance from a square's center to its edges

Tags: calculus

The question is self explanatory.

Let me quickly explain my approach, and one of you smart fellows point out where I'm going wrong.

*(I want to do this in **polar** on purpose. I feel I could probably do it in rectangular (since I did many similar problems in calc 3 class), but my polar is really weak and I want to improve it)*

I called the distance from origin to edge at some angle theta: $d(\theta)$.

I imagined a circle within the square whose radius $r$ is a constant, and is equal to $d(0)$.

Since I'm looking for the *average* distance, I can integrate $d(\theta)$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$, and then multiply the result by $1 / (2\pi)$.

Before I attempt to define our $d(\theta)$, I make another observation. Because of symmetry, I can just work with a $\pi / 4$ radian section, and generalize on that, since the average over the $\pi / 4$ section will be equal to the average over the entire square.

Now, to define $d(\theta)$.

My definition was: $d(\theta) = \sqrt{r^2 + (r\tan(\theta))^2}$

And plug the $d(\theta)$ into below integral:

$(1/(0.25\pi)) (0.5) \int(d(\theta))^2d\theta$ on the interval $[0, 0.25\pi]$

*(Note that the first multiplier is because I am calculating the average over that interval. The second multiplier comes from the polar integral formula $\int((1/2)r^2)d\theta$.)*

Now, I will spare you my subsequent computations, as they were a bit messy and I don't want to include them. My result is way too large and obviously incorrect.

**Have you spotted an error in how I set this up?** If not, I must be making a mistake in the computation.

I'd also greatly appreciate any additional wisdom. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you squaring $r$? That "polar integral formula" is the integral for the area. That's fine if what you're trying to do is to calculate the area of a square with side $2r$, but that's not the problem you claim to be trying to solve.

Now, one thing to watch for - the average depends on the probability distribution. Your setup here looks like a uniform distribution with respect to angle, while the rectangular coordinate setup you alluded to implies a uniform distribution with respect to length. Those are not the same thing; the latter should result in a slightly larger average distance. Make sure to be clear exactly what you're trying to find - the question is not as self-explanatory as you think.

In better news, your distance formula is correct for a square of side $2r$, and the reduction to an interval of length $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is good. Those parts won't cause problems.

Comment: Thank you, you've blown my mind. I fully understand what you mean by the difference between the rectangular form I've mentioned (which would assume equal likelihood of landing on a unit length along the edges), versus what I've attempted (which assumes an equal likelihood of us starting from each unit angle). And I understand why the former would yield a slightly greater result. I had never thought of this, thank you.

My question assumes a uniform probability distribution for angles. Given a random starting *orientation*, how long should an ant travel to get out of the square.

Comment: About squaring the r... The little rules like why we include an additional R in double polar integrals and why polar area integral does a "one half r squared" has never been explained to me, so it remains as black magic. That's probably why I use it where I shouldn't, because I simply don't understand it. Thanks for pointing it out, I will read on this particular topic and try to get a deeper understanding. Again, thanks for the amazing response.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but wanted to propose my approach. Given a square whose verteces have coordiantes $A(r,r)$, $B(-r,r)$, $C(-r,-r)$, and $D(r,-r)$, we want to determine the average distance from the origin of the points on its perimeter. Of course, by symmerty, as you pointed out, we can just work between $(r,0)$ and $A(r,r)$. The distance of point $P(r,y)$ is
$$d(y)= \sqrt{r^2+y^2}.$$
So in cartesian coordinates the integral would be
$$\overline d = \frac{1}{r}\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2+y^2}dy.$$
If you want to work with the angle $\theta$ then the change of variable would be
$$y = r\tan\theta.$$
Which means
$$\theta = \arctan\frac{y}{r}.$$
Differentiating yields
$$ d\theta = \frac{r}{r^2+y^2}dy.$$
Therefore the integral becomes
$$\overline d=\frac{1}{r^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(r^2+r^2\tan^2\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}d\theta.$$
**EDITED** thanks to [jmerry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/619637/jmerry). Hope now it's fine...

Comment: There's a mistake there - you've got units of $\text{length}^{-1}$ for your average distance, because you multiplied when you should have divided.

Comment: right!! I'll correct it right away. Thanks!

Comment: @jmerry do you think it is correct now?

Comment: It is now a properly set up integral (for the average over the length-uniform distribution).

Comment: @jmerry yes, as you pointed out, the distribution hypothesis is very important. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, thank you. However, I can't select this as the answer because I was going for a uniform prob distribution with respect to angle. I do appreciate it though. And soz for not being clear enough.